"Overscrolling" nested ListViews in Flutter
I have the following code to demonstrate a problem I'm having. I have a nested ListView, and I want the child's scrolling to "surrender" to the parent's when the user reaches the end or start of the child.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Scroll example',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          body: ListView(
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) ListItem(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 120,
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) ListItem2(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) ListItem(),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class ListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('Item'),
      tileColor: Colors.blue,
    );
  }
}

class ListItem2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('Item',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.red,
          )),
    );
  }
}

I also have recorded a demo of the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmaR9rYMGd4
Also, here is an example of it working as I would expect it to in Flutter on web:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLxyPpb94M4
Output of flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.4, on macOS 13.5 22G74 darwin-arm64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.88.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!


this might be a reference : https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_scroll_view

That is a low-quality library that does not solve my issue.

I'm not saying you shouldn't use it. Since you say it is low quality, I can assume you are an expert.  So you may read the code in the repository, see how it works, then modify based on your needs.

As I said, it does not solve my problem, as my use case is not listed in its readme. I don't think you understand the problem I have put forth in my question.

Hi @DaraJ. I tried to run your code. It's working as expected. when the child list view reaches the end then the parent list taking control and scroll. and when child list is reaching at the top then also the parent list is scrolling as shown in expected video. which Flutter version you are using?

@Aks
Thanks for testing. I have added the output of flutter doctor to the question, it's 3.19.4. What version are you on?

@Aks what platform did you test on?

platform: flutter web, flutter-version: 3.19.6

You can see the result here: https://jmp.sh/gcKEmcC8

Yes, I see. It works for me on web too. Does not work on ios or macos. Seems like a bug in Flutter.

have you tried to set physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() . or even AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()

@A-E Yes - NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() just disables the scrolling, and AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() has no effect.

You just need to use ScrollController, NotificationListener and play with some scrollExtents and offsets.
Check out the below code. It will do the job. Hope this will be helpful in your use-case.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Scroll example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          controller: controller,
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) ListItem(),
            Container(
              height: 120,
              child: NotificationListener<OverscrollNotification>(
                onNotification: (OverscrollNotification value) {
                  if (value.overscroll < 0 &&
                      controller.offset + value.overscroll <= 0) {
                    if (controller.offset != 0) controller.jumpTo(0);
                    return true;
                  }
                  if (controller.offset + value.overscroll >=
                      controller.position.maxScrollExtent) {
                    if (controller.offset !=
                        controller.position.maxScrollExtent) {
                      controller.jumpTo(controller.position.maxScrollExtent);
                    }
                    return true;
                  }
                  controller.jumpTo(controller.offset + value.overscroll);
                  return true;
                },
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) ListItem2(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) ListItem(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('Item'),
      tileColor: Colors.blue,
    );
  }
}

class ListItem2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('Item',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.red,
          )),
    );
  }
}

